# Функция генерации нулей

Tags: php, интернет-магазин

есть кусок кода

```
$amount = $params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, 3);
```

это цена, которую генерирует инет магазин. она может быть как `100` так и `1000`

как сделать, чтобы перед суммой, выводились нули.

например: если итоговая сумма `1700` - то вывод `0000001700`
если `100` - то вывод `0000000100`

то есть всего 10 символов должно быть
Если не затруднит, прям в тот кусок кода воткнуть...

Answer (score 2):

Уже было не единожды.

```
$val = 23;
printf("%'010s",$val);
```

Comment: $amount = $params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, 3); - было

$amount = printf("%'010s",$params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, 3)); - так что ли?

Comment: @sweetcoder замените на http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php

Comment: $amount = sprintf("%'010s",$params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, 3));

@lampa сказал правильно.

Comment: Спасибо,ага работает :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$amount = $params['cart']->getOrderTotal(true, 3);
$sc = array(strlen($amount),10-strlen($amount));

$fs = '';
for($i=0;$i<$sc[1];$i++) {$fs .= '0';}

$amount = $fs.$amount;
```

Comment: не красиво, но просто и работает

Comment: А число к строке не нужно приводить? А то мне кажется strlen не сработает.

Comment: не нужно. PHP сам переведет

Comment: и этот работает :)

Comment: не могу к сожалению палец вверх поставить)...

Comment: лечите палец!)))